# ERROR TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'animationRef.current.play')

Tags: react-native, expo, lottie

**Error Description:**
I am trying to play a lottie animation once my homescreen component mounts. The animation is supposed to be played once after log in and then it should just go away. but I keep getting this error. (it's like a success log in animation)
This error occurs the first time when I try to save a change. But when I save my code again it goes away. Like I dont even do anything I just have to save my code twice for this to go away and everytime it just throws me back to initial screen which is really frustrating because I gotta log in again to come to my working screen and all. Also, I am concerned that it may ruin my app's progress once I launch its apk.

**PS***I am new to react native so, I dont really know if this is the best solution for what I am trying to acieve, if you know a better alternative. I would be glad to try it. Thanks in anticipation*

**My Code:**

```
const [animationVisible, setAnimationVisible] = useState(true);
const animationRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    // Play the animation when the component mounts
    animationRef.current.play();
  }, []);

const onAnimationFinish = () => {
  setAnimationVisible(false);
};
return (
    <View style = {styles.homecontainer}>
      {animationVisible && (
    <LottieView
      ref={animationRef}
      source={require('./assets/lottie/success.json')} 
      autoPlay={false}
      loop={false}
      onAnimationFinish={onAnimationFinish}
      style = {styles.successlottie}
    />
  )}
    </View>
);
```